# Android How to Increase View Pager PageStrip Size?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have been searching the solution for how to increase the View pager PageStrip size. 
After the long search i have found from here, The **INDICATOR_HEIGHT = 3; // dp** 
have been hard coded. 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/24cc55cb5775a71ff144a3588003fa8e52951c7d/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.java

Is there any way to increase this ? 
See the attached image . the red strip is what i want. [image]

Hoping for better Response.

**EDIT**

**View Pager Indicator Library with my Input Title.** 
[image]

Comment: You are probably going to have to fork the class, or perhaps switch to a more flexible implementation, such as the `TabPageIndicator` from [the ViewPagerIndicator library](http://viewpagerindicator.com).

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare I am using above library only. If i use  that library my pager titles left and right text are looks very close. how to increase the padding between titles ?

Comment: Hello @CommonsWare i have just forked the ViewPagerIndicator library from github and have given the input which i want.  The problem is i want to provide the padding .. please see the attached image. for reference.

Comment: ViewPagerIndicator can be adjusted via themes. See their sample apps, or see https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/VPI

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare If i use your view pager it totally changed my app theme with different colors and loader have got changed . but what i am expected was not changed.

Comment: It was **an example**, showing how you can use a theme to change the behavior of a `TabPageIndicator`. It is up to *you* to do the research to figure out if whatever *you* want changed can also be changed via a theme. Again, look at the ViewPagerIndicator sample apps, or even its source code.